# Change background colour on mouse over of all rows in table which all are present after particular class using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a table with multiple rows.I am using the first row as table header and differentiated it using CSS.

Now I want to change background colour for all the remaining rows with in that table on mouse over using CSS. But the header row background should not be changed.

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" width="100%" id="table1">
<tr class="headerStyle">
<td>Sl.No</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Code</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Name1</td>
<td>Code1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Name2</td>
<td>Code2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>Name3</td>
<td>Code3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.headerStyle {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-color: #07889b;
}

.headerStyle + tr:hover {
    background-color: #bedcfc;
}
```

I tried many suggestions from stackoverflow, but didn't worked.

I tried the above finally, but it changing the first row's background colour only.

Is there any possibility in CSS?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `<th>` tag, that's why it exists. Now you got two differents tags, you can style individually.

Comment: @Paul the `th` element should be used instead of the `td` element if the cell represents the header cell. So it would not have any effect on the `tr` element here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` is for [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), you looking for the `~` ([General sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).).

But for a correct semantic structure the header of a table should be in the `thead` tag of your `table`, and the rest of the rows should be in the `tbody`. The way you wrote it all of your `tr` element would be automatically placed in the `tbody`. And for the header you should use `th` and not `td`.

So your structure should look like that:

```
<table border="1" width="100%" id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sl.No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Name1</td>
      <td>Code1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Name2</td>
      <td>Code2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Name3</td>
      <td>Code3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you structure your table that way you would have a correct semantic structure, and you would not have a problem with your css rules:

```
thead tr {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: #07889b;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #bedcfc;
}
```

If you do not want to structure your code that way then the css rule would have to be:

```
.headerStyle ~ tr:hover {
    background-color: #bedcfc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @t.niese. This is what i expected and working correctly

Comment: Good and knowledgeable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in you css

```
.headerStyle 
{
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: #07889b;
}

tr:hover:not(.headerStyle):hover 
{
  background-color: #bedcfc;
}
```

If you have more than one table in your code then try giving your tables different class. You can see the example below.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/14731kvf/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have some other tables also in that page. This is changing that table's background also

Comment: then give your table a class and then use css

Comment: Thanks @Sidharth Gusain

Comment: I have updated my answer you can see the demo from there.

Comment: Just as a note: you have two `:hover` in the selector. You might want to write only `tr:not(.headerStyle):hover`

Answer (score 0):

check updated fiddle...
is that what you need ?

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/maky/ho83vre7/1/)

```
.headerStyle {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: #07889b;
}
tr:hover {
  background-color: #bedcfc;
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't apply to the the `<tr>` tags in `.headerStyle` I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mariusz. This will change the background of first tr too. The first tr background should not be changed in my case

Comment: check the fiddle again

Answer (score 0):

Your css code for the tr is changing background for all the rows. Your table html should have thead and tbody tags to avoid this problem.Proper table structure should be like:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="xyz">
      <td>.....</td>
      ........
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      ............
    </tr>
    ................
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However if you don't want to change your current html then to avoid css from changing background of your header row, you can use css to keep the header row background same on hover. You can do it by altering your css this way:

```
.headerStyle {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-color: #07889b;
}
tr.headerStyle:hover {
  background-color: #07889b;
}
 tr:hover {
    background-color: #bedcfc;
}
```